# Is it safe to cast void (*p)(SomeType*) to void (*p)(void*)

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function like below:

```
void fun(void* p){
    SomeType* p = reinterpret_cast<SomeType*>(p);
    ...
}
```

The signature is require by the api. I just wonder can I just write it as.

```
void fun(SomeType* p){
    ...
}
```

And cast it to `void (*)(void*)`.

Comment: `void fun(void* p)` is required by the api?

Comment: No, the two are not compatible types. Also, a static cast will do from `void*` to any other object pointer.

Comment: You will invoke Undefined Behavior by casting `void(*)(SomeType*)` to `void (*)(void*)` and calling it through the new type. It violates the Strict aliasing rule

Comment: Why not wrap the API in a type-safe way?

Comment: The cast is "safe" for pretty much any reasonable definition of "safe". Whether or not you can **use** the result of the cast depends on what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you can cast function pointers to other function pointers and back, calling a function through a pointer that doesn't match its signature is undefined behavior. You cannot just cast it and pass to an API.

In C and C++03, you'd have to create a named wrapper function that matches the signature and preforms the cast. In C++11 and beyond, you can just use a capture-less lambda instead (properly cast):

```
void fun(SomeType* p){
    ...
}

int main() {
  api_call(+[](void *v) {
    fun(static_cast<SomeType*>(v));
  });
}
```

The `+` in front of the lambda causes it to be converted into a regular function pointer so long as it's not capturing. It's not strictly needed, but it makes the intent more explicit IMO, without too much verbosity.

Comment: What's happening with the `+ ` to force a conversion?

Comment: @PasserBy - [Some code to illustrate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/897ea4f381d0cf2b). Unary + is defined for all pointer types (it doesn't change the value of the pointer, but can be applied). Since c++ wants to be a helpful language, it will apply any (non-explicit) conversion operator on the closure object to make the expression valid. Thus the + becomes a shorthand for casting :)

Comment: But this just move the cast out of the function. I have many different `SomeTypeN`. I wan't to wrap the `api_call` in a template function which accept a type safe signature.  capture-less lambda won't help.

Comment: @J.Doe - Well, then go ahead and wrap the API. Would probably be more beneficial in the log run. You only asked about the validity of the function cast itself, and I answered that. I understood that you wish to avoid the boilerplate for your function, so I addressed that as well. Your mileage may vary of course.

Comment: @StoryTeller The problem is the wrap requires a cast which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @J.Doe - There is more than one way to wrap an API. You don't *have* to cast. If this is a C library we are talking about, you may get some pointers from [this CPPCon2014 lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZO0V4Prefc).